# Convert Special characters into Html Encoded characters

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, special-characters

I want to converter all special characters into Html encoded characters.
I found many post related to used `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode();` ,
but it's only convert some of special characters like `"&", "<", ">"`.

Is there any way to convert all special character like `"š","Ø","þ","›","Ù"` into Html entity using C# or javascript?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Microsoft AntiXss Library](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/confirmation.aspx?id=28589) can accomplish this;

```
string p = Microsoft.Security.Application.Encoder.HtmlEncode("aaa <b>sdf</b> š,Ø,þ,›,Ù", true);
Response.Write(p);
```

For

```
aaa &lt;b&gt;sdf&lt;/b&gt; &scaron;,&Oslash;,&thorn;,&rsaquo;,&Ugrave;
```

Comment: escape needs no libraries.Right ?? Do we really need a library ?

Comment: This is a way to do it if you want it escaped server-side

Comment: HtmlTextWriter also has WriteEncodedText Method see the post below

Answer (score 5):

you can also do as follows without AntiXSS

```
public static string HtmlEncode (string text)
{
    string result;
    using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        var x = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        x.WriteEncodedText(text);
        result = sw.ToString();
    }
    return result;

}
```

Comment: FYI, you need to reference System.Web

Answer (score 4):

Yes.Using javascript [Escape them](http://www.yuki-onna.co.uk/html/encode.html).

```
document.write(escape("3423424242<><><$$"));
```

Comment: I don't get this. Why are you solving something which Ishan has already solved? Or am I missing something? I mean, will escape replace characters like "š","Ø","þ","›","Ù" with corresponding % value?

Comment: please check in the demo link i shared.It also encodes all special chars.