# C# Convert unicode character to HTML entity (name)

Tags: c#, unicode, utf-8

I would like to convert Unicode text

```
Text with accent é
```

to

```
Text with accent &eacute;
```

---

'System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode' and 'System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode' will produce

```
Text with accent &#233;
```

Using an System.Xml.XmlWriter with ASCII encoding results in

```
Text with accent &#xE9;
```

---

I need the name not any hex or decimal code.
I found many entity names here: https://unicode-table.com/en/html-entities/

Is there maybe some kind of library available?

Edit:
My target is to have an ASCII encoded file (XML) that uses entity NAMES instead of CODES.
If some codes no do have an entity NAME then they should be null (or the CODE).
This is a requirement for a project.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Your example of the "'System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode' and 'System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode'" that produces &#233; should be perfectly interpretable in html  as an "é"

Comment: In the end I want an XML with entity NAMES instead of codes. It is a requirement for a project.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Special characters into Html Encoded characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17106949/convert-special-characters-into-html-encoded-characters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a more official reference: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/named-characters.html

The HTML entity list will probably keep growing in the future so you need a dynamic solution. Here is how I would do it (using [HtmlAgilityPack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack/)):

```
private string ConvertCharsToHTMLEntities(string text)
{
    string res = "";
    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
        // Getting the HTML entities table 
        string page = client.DownloadString("https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/named-characters.html");
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(page);
        List<List<string>> table = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='named-character-references-table']//table")
                    .Descendants("tr")
                    .Skip(1)
                    .Where(tr => tr.Elements("td").Count() > 1)
                    .Select(tr => tr.Elements("td").Select(td => td.InnerText.Trim()).ToList())
                    .ToList();

        // Converting the table to pairs of code point and HTML entity 
        Dictionary<string, string> entitys = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        table.ForEach(a => a[1].Split(' ').ToList().ForEach(b => entitys[b] = a[0]));

        // recreating the string with replacing code point to HTML entity
        foreach (char c in text)
        {
            string codePoint = string.Format("U+{0:X5}", Convert.ToUInt32(c));
            res += entitys.ContainsKey(codePoint) ? entitys[codePoint] : c.ToString();
        }
    }

    return res;
}
```

Comment: The website is a good hint. At the bottom there is a download link for a JSON file containing all these entities (I hope it will be kept up to date). So no need to parse the DOM.  So I have exactly what I need: A list of entity names with their associated codes.  I have also found something similar here: http://www.w3.org/2003/entities/2007/w3centities-f.ent

Comment: oh Cool &smile; yeah using the json link https://html.spec.whatwg.org/entities.json or the XML link you gave will be much cleaner.

Comment: We did here good work but I just found a similar stack overflow post that offer an [out of the box solution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.security.antixss.antixssencoder.htmlencode) for .NET Framework 4.8 and above: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17106949/convert-special-characters-into-html-encoded-characters